# How to install Debian 11 into logical volumes dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, lvm, debian-installer

I've used Debian or Devuan for a long time.  AFAICR it was possible to do a manual install into existing LVM logical vols so I could format & reuse the partitions for root, /usr & so on but keep  that for /home.  I've just been trying to overwrite the old install on a dual-boot with Windows and I find that all the LVM partitions are blocked from use.  As it's dual-boot I can't do a guided install that uses the whole disk without overwriting the Windows partition.  It may be that memory is playing false (at my age quite possible!) & I never could do this or has something changed?  How do I work round it without going the long way round and setting up a minimal install on a plain partition, installing LVM & then moving everything into the logical volumes?